# Unable to open Windows Disk partitions in solaris 11

Tags: solaris, disk

I have recently installed solaris 11, but I am an absolute beginner in unix systems. The only unix like environment I have got myself into before is ubuntu which was quite a bit different from solaris in my opinion. The main problem I am facing at the moment is that the NTFS windows HD partitions are not appearing in solaris file system, which was not the case when I used ubuntu. Every single file on my HD was exposed to me when I was in ubuntu.

I have already tried to find the solution in the internet. Tried to solve it with the help of [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/mandalika/entry/mounting_windows_ntfs_on_open) But had no success. The download links given for both FSWpart and FSWfsmisc is not working(giving a 404). I installed something called ntfs -g drive but I think I am not using it correctly as most of the time I am copying and pasting commands because I do not have sufficient knowledge to write them myself.

Please any assistance in this matter is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.